# Tradingview Strategy applying via pine script - following error's

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Ive inputed the following script into the pine script on tradingview and got a bunch of errors:

- Error at 10:52 The function 'ta.change' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope
- Error at 17:17 Too many arguments
- Error at 18:18 Too many arguments
- Error at 19:13 Undeclared identifier 'tr'
- Error at 22:19 Could not find function or function reference 'abs'
- Error at 40:14 Too many arguments
- Error at 45:85 Cannot call 'operator >' with argument 'expr0'='call 'operator not' (series bool)'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'const float' is expected.
- Error at 46:5 The `when` parameter will be deprecated in future Pine versions. We recommend using `if` or `switch` conditional blocks instead.
- Eror at 49:83 Cannot call 'operator <' with argument 'expr0'='call 'operator not' (series bool)'. An argument of 'series bool' type was used but a 'const float' is expected.
- Eror at 50:5 The `when` parameter will be deprecated in future Pine versions. We recommend using `if` or `switch` conditional blocks instead.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bull Trading 1 Minute Scalping Sys v3.0", overlay=true)

// Indicator 1: Bull Trading 1 Minute Easy Scalping Sys v3.0
bullTradingColor = input(color.white, "Bull Trading Color")
bullTrading = false
bullTradingCondition = ta.change(close) > 0 ? 1 : (ta.change(close) < 0 ? -1 : 0)
bullTrading := bullTradingCondition != 0 ? bullTradingCondition : bullTrading
longCondition = bullTrading and bullTradingCondition == 1
shortCondition = bullTrading and bullTradingCondition == -1

// Indicator 2: ADX and DI
adxPeriod = input(14, "ADX Period")
plusDM = ta.max(high - high[1], 0)
minusDM = ta.max(low[1] - low, 0)
tr = ta.rma(tr, adxPeriod)
plusDI = 100 * ta.rma(plusDM, adxPeriod) / tr
minusDI = 100 * ta.rma(minusDM, adxPeriod) / tr
dx = 100 * ta.rma(abs(plusDI - minusDI) / (plusDI + minusDI), adxPeriod)
adx = ta.rma(dx, adxPeriod)

whiteLineCrossesBelowOrange = ta.crossover(plusDI, minusDI) == 1
whiteLineCrossesAboveOrange = ta.crossunder(plusDI, minusDI) == 1

// Indicator 3: Candle Color
candleColor = close >= open ? color.white : color.red

// Indicator 4: Color Switch
lastColor = 0.0
colorSwitch = bullTradingCondition != 0
if colorSwitch
    lastColor := bullTradingCondition

// Indicator 5: ATR Stop Loss Finder
atrPeriod = input(14, "ATR Period")
atrMultiplier = input(2.0, "ATR Multiplier")
atr = ta.atr(high, low, close, atrPeriod)
stopLossPrice = lastColor > 0 ? close - atrMultiplier * atr : close + atrMultiplier * atr
takeProfitPrice = lastColor > 0 ? close + 1.5 * atr : close - 1.5 * atr

// Trading Logic
if longCondition and whiteLineCrossesAboveOrange and candleColor == color.white and not strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = barstate.isconfirmed)
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Long", stop = stopLossPrice)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Long", limit = takeProfitPrice)
if shortCondition and whiteLineCrossesBelowOrange and candleColor == color.red and not strategy.position_size < 0
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = barstate.isconfirmed)
    strategy.exit("Stop Loss", "Short", stop = stopLossPrice)
    strategy.exit("Take Profit", "Short", limit = takeProfitPrice)
```

Could anyone help, that would be amazing!
Thank You!

I tried coding a tradin strategy into pine script to backtest the trading strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote ur script to fix the errors youll have to mess with the long and short condition to make them profitbale on the 1 minute which is gonna be hard because the 1 minute is awful for trading

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bull Trading 1 Minute Scalping Sys v3.0", overlay=true)

// Indicator 1: Bull Trading 1 Minute Easy Scalping Sys v3.0

bullTradingColor = input(color.white, "Bull Trading Color")
bullTrading = false
bullTradingCondition = ta.change(close)
bullTrading := bullTradingCondition > 0 ? 1 : (bullTradingCondition < 0 ? -1 : bullTrading)
longCondition = bullTrading and bullTradingCondition == 1
shortCondition = bullTrading and bullTradingCondition == -1
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=14, minval=1)
adxPeriod = input(14, "ADX Period")
smoothing = input.string(title="Smoothing", defval="RMA", options=["RMA", "SMA", "EMA", "WMA"])
ma_function(source, adxPeriod) =>
    switch smoothing
        "RMA" => ta.rma(source, adxPeriod)
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, adxPeriod)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, adxPeriod)
// Indicator 2: ADX and DI
plusDM = ta.max(high - high[1])
minusDM = ta.max(low[1] - low)
atr = ma_function(ta.tr(true), adxPeriod)
plusDI = 100 * ta.rma(plusDM, adxPeriod) / atr
minusDI = 100 * ta.rma(minusDM, adxPeriod) / atr
dx = 100 * ta.rma(math.abs(plusDI - minusDI) / (plusDI + minusDI), adxPeriod)
adx = ta.rma(dx, adxPeriod)

whiteLineCrossesBelowOrange = ta.crossover(plusDI, minusDI) == 1
whiteLineCrossesAboveOrange = ta.crossunder(plusDI, minusDI) == 1

// Indicator 3: Candle Color
candleColorRed = close >= open 
candleColorGreen = close <= open


// Indicator 4: Color Switch
var lastColor = 0.0
colorSwitch = bullTradingCondition != 0
if colorSwitch
    lastColor := bullTradingCondition

// Indicator 5: ATR Stop Loss Finder
atrPeriod = input(14, "ATR Period")
atrMultiplier = input(2.0, "ATR Multiplier")
stopLossPrice = lastColor > 0 ? close - atrMultiplier * atr : close + atrMultiplier * atr
takeProfitPrice = lastColor > 0 ? close + 1.5 * atr : close - 1.5 * atr

// Trading Logic
if barstate.isconfirmed and (longCondition and candleColorRed) or whiteLineCrossesAboveOrange
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Long" , comment = "SL",  stop = stopLossPrice)
    strategy.exit("Long", comment = "TP", limit = takeProfitPrice)
if barstate.isconfirmed and (shortCondition and candleColorRed) or whiteLineCrossesBelowOrange 
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Short", comment = "SL" , stop = stopLossPrice)
    strategy.exit("Short", comment = "TP" , limit = takeProfitPrice)
```

Comment: Yeah i know, 1.5 Risk to reward is not that good but its the best for percentage of profitability. I think the code isn't right yet though, I mean it works now so thank you! but I think its not right. If you got time could you update it so it meets these points:

1. condition: If Indicator "(Bull Trading) 1 minute Easy Scalping Sys v3.0" turns white, go long, if it turns red go short.
2. condition: If condition one is true look for the next cross on the "ADX and DI" Indicator. If the white line crosses bellow the orange line go short if the white line goes above the orange line go long.

Comment: 3. condition: if the conditions above are true, look for a white candle (body) if going long and look for a red candle (body) if going short. Once you find the first red or white candle, wait until it closes and enter the trade as soon as its closed. 
4. condition: Once entered a trade, wait until the  Indicator "(Bull Trading) 1 minute Easy Scalping Sys v3.0" switches colors again. Only ever enter one trade for every color switch.

Comment: 5. condition: if going long following the above indications, place the stop loss right on the green line of the indicator "ATR Stop Loss Finder". So if you find a white candle to go long, once that candle closes and you enter the trade, place the stop loss on the green line on exactly that candle. For the Take profit level, use the stop loss level and use a risk to reward ratio of exactly 1.5. For a sell position do the exact same tactic but use the red line to place the stop loss level and place it on a red candle and not a white one.

Comment: sorry im not here to code you a script I can slightly modify a script your writing to fix syntax errors and undeclared or to many arguments errors like u had but I'm definitely not here to rewrite your whole script.